# why Spring social facebook -2.0.3 using deprecated graph api version 2.5 which is deprecated

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

We are using spring-social-facebook-2.0.3 latest jar in production environment.

In April 2018 graph api v2.5 is going to shut down. But the spring-social-facebook-2.0.3 latest jar is still using this deprecated graph API internally.

Anyone has any knowledge, 
**is Spring Team going to release new version of spring-social-facebook till next month (i.e April 2018)?**

Comment: Should not matter much even if they didn’t, because API calls specifying an outdated API version are automatically converted to using the lowest currently available version.

Comment: @CBroe: could you please elaborate it more. Actually what i see in spring-social jar, it is using hardcoded graph version 2.5. So how it will point to lowest available version automatically. We are actually worry taking Production app, will it work properly?

Comment: Facebook takes care of that on their end - your app makes a request using an API version that is not available any more, so they automatically & silently treat it as if it was made using the lowest available version.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. you seem very accurate to me. But my company is not relying on your words until they see any proof from Facebook. It's a question of their production app used by half million users. So can you share any written document which shows it? if possible. Or any other source.

Comment: _“It's a question of their production app used by half million users”_ - good for them. Although in that case, I’d have expected them to properly prepare for this themselves to begin with ... and not outsource it to SO last minute.

Comment: Official Facebook documentation that backs up @CBroe's statement:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions.  It says "For APIs, once a version is no longer usable, any calls made to it will be defaulted to the next oldest usable version."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for those who wants to change used API version in 2.0.3 Release and Facebook API Upgrade Tool says it does not affect them applications:

```
public class FacebookCustomApiVersionConnectionFactory extends OAuth2ConnectionFactory<Facebook> {

  public FacebookCustomApiVersionConnectionFactory(String apiVersion, String appId, String appSecret) {
    super("facebook", new FacebookCustomApiVersionServiceProvider(apiVersion, appId, appSecret, null), new FacebookAdapter());
  }
}


/**
 * Facebook ServiceProvider implementation that allows to change Facebook API version.
 */
public class FacebookCustomApiVersionServiceProvider extends AbstractOAuth2ServiceProvider<Facebook> {

  private final String appNamespace;

  private final String apiVersion;

  /**
   * Creates a FacebookServiceProvider for the given API version, application ID, secret, and namespace.
   *
   * @param apiVersion   Facebook API version
   * @param appId        The application's App ID as assigned by Facebook
   * @param appSecret    The application's App Secret as assigned by Facebook
   * @param appNamespace The application's App Namespace as configured with Facebook. Enables use of Open Graph operations.
   */
  public FacebookCustomApiVersionServiceProvider(String apiVersion, String appId, String appSecret, String appNamespace) {
    super(getOAuth2Template(apiVersion, "https://graph.facebook.com/v" + apiVersion + "/", appId, appSecret));
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
    this.appNamespace = appNamespace;
  }

  private static OAuth2Template getOAuth2Template(String apiVersion, String graphApiUrl, String appId, String appSecret) {
    OAuth2Template oAuth2Template = new OAuth2Template(appId, appSecret,
            "https://www.facebook.com/v" + apiVersion + "/dialog/oauth",
            graphApiUrl + "oauth/access_token");
    oAuth2Template.setUseParametersForClientAuthentication(true);
    return oAuth2Template;
  }

  public Facebook getApi(String accessToken) {
    FacebookTemplate facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken, appNamespace);
    facebook.setApiVersion(apiVersion);
    return facebook;
  }
}
```

**Spring social configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookCustomApiVersionConnectionFactory("2.7", "appId","appSecret");

  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply change api version by following way

```
FacebookTemplate facebookTemplate=new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
facebookTemplate.setApiVersion("3.2");
System.out.println("graph url"+facebookTemplate.getBaseGraphApiUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

That project is obselete. They announced the end of life in 2018 to be effective in 2019:
https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement

They recommand to simply use Spring Security instead.